# Meaning and usage of complex number functor and monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, complex-numbers, applicative

I was kinda surprised when I read the source code of instances of `Applicative Complex` and `Monad Complex` from GHC `Data.Complex` module:

```
-- | @since 4.9.0.0
instance Applicative Complex where
  pure a = a :+ a
  f :+ g <*> a :+ b = f a :+ g b
  liftA2 f (x :+ y) (a :+ b) = f x a :+ f y b

-- | @since 4.9.0.0
instance Monad Complex where
  a :+ b >>= f = realPart (f a) :+ imagPart (f b)
```

What the...? The `Applicative Complex` instance seems to treat complex numbers as just size-two arrays. And they both seem more like arrow operations. Is there any mathematical basis behind them? Either there is or not, what are they used for?

Comment: They are law-abiding instances, so there is no reason for them not to exist (this is the 'mathematical' basis)

Comment: So there are no connections to complex analysis, and complex numbers are just size-two arrays here?

Comment: Complex numbers *are*, in some sense, just arrays of size 2. ℂ is isomorphic to ℝ².

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Edited* to add note at bottom re: "linear" package.

The instances were added as per this [Trac 10609 ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10609) initiated by [a mailing list post](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2015-June/025886.html) where Fumiaki Kinoshita noted that there were some missing instances in the base libraries that seemed to be definable in only one way and proposed a patch to add them.

As far as I can see, there was no mathematical motivation for adding them, though there's at least one mathematically meaningful operation that can be expressed applicatively, namely scalar multiplication:

```
> pure (*) <*> pure 2 <*> (3 :+ 4)
6 :+ 8
>
```

In a [follow-up](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2015-June/025897.html) to the above mailing list post, Edward Kmett noted that he was in favor because he'd had to add orphan instances for `Complex` to his `linear` package for years to make up for the missing instances.

It looks like he found them useful in defining an `Additive` instance for `Complex` thus essentially making a `Complex` a special case of a two dimensional vector.

Comment: Why use `pure f <*> pure a <*> b` instead of `f a <$> b`?

Answer (score 2):

(Posting an answer since I don't have reputation to make comments, free feel to adjust.)

[K. A. Buhr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7203016/k-a-buhr)'s answer addresses everything except the `Monad` instance, which is most strange. There is a mathematically obvious sense in which `Complex` does form a monad, prescribed by the equation `(a + bi) + (c + di)i = (a - d) + (b + c)i`. Of course, this requires that we work over a type class with notions of addition and subtraction.

(Contra [user2407038](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2407038/user2407038), then: there is a good reason for this `Monad` instance to not exist even though it is "law-abiding": it is not the instance that implements expected behavior.)

By the way: this was briefly discussed in this [blog post](https://vitez.me/complex-monad).

Comment: Agree that this is a good reason against the instance existing. I wish Haskellers stopped doing this kind of stuff.